# javascript binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself

Tags: javascript, tree

I learn javascript recently, I don't know why the code I wrote is wrong. Here is the quesion:Given a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself.

```
var isSymmetric = function(root) {
if(root === null) return true;
function isSymmetric(leftNode, rightNode){
    if(leftNode === null && rightNode === null) return true;
    if(leftNode === null || rightNode === null) return false;
    return (leftNode.val == rightNode.val) && isSymmetric(leftNode.left, rightNode.right) && isSymmetric(leftNode.right, rightNode.left);
}
isSymmetric(root.left, root.right);
```

};
when the input is 1, the result is "undefined". This algorithm is transformed from my Java code. Please kindly inform me where I get wrong.

Comment: the inner function isSymmetric is never called

Comment: @JaromandaX but the last line I try to call the inner function, and how to correct the code?

Comment: no, wait. it is, but the last line you show should be **return** isSymmetric( etc - you haven't shown the closing } of the outer function, so i was confused :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var isSymmetric = function(root) {
        if (root === null) return true;

        function isSymmetric(leftNode, rightNode) {
            if (leftNode === null && rightNode === null) return true;
            if (leftNode === null || rightNode === null) return false;
            return (leftNode.val == rightNode.val) && isSymmetric(leftNode.left, rightNode.right) && isSymmetric(leftNode.right, rightNode.left);
        }
        return isSymmetric(root.left, root.right);
};
```

you need to return the result of isSymmetric as shown above

personally, I wouldn't have the outer and inner functions have the same name, it looks confusing to my old eyes :p

Comment: Yes, now its working. Guess I'm still not fully understand the syntax of JavaScript. A long way to go.